# Как создать виртуальный CAN порт в linux?

Tags: linux, c, port, virtual, can

Я хочу создать программу которая  будет эмулировать CAN порт для тестирования другого большого приложения. Программа должна оправлять ранее записанные данные, через виртуальный CAN порт. У кого нибудь есть опыт работы с такими вещами?

Я думаю установить виртуальный COM и отправить через него данные, упакованные в CAN фрейм. Этот вариант действий может иметь успех ?? Нашёл обсуждение Virtual Serial Port для Linux, но к сожалению я не понимаю как это может быть реализовано в программе (являюсь начинающим пользователем Linux, а также являюсь начинающим погромистом в Linux)

Хотелось бы почитать ваш опыт и предложения.

---

*вопрос является [переводом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022749/how-to-create-virtual-can-port-on-linux-c)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе просто нужен [SocketCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN) драйвер, деловая колбаса :3  он доступен в современных дистрибутивах таких как Ubuntu и Debian и т.д. SocketCAN предоставляет драйвер виртуальный порт CAN:

```
sudo modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ip link set up vcan0
```

Теперь вы можете отправлять и получать кадры CAN через vcan0 устройство. Статья Википедии предоставляет простой пример кода и поясняет о том как использовать SocketCAN.

Вам также понадобятся [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) для тестирования программы.

Вы также найдёте больше информации о SocketCAN и его использовании на сайте [eLinux.org](https://elinux.org/CAN_Bus).

Пример работы с физический портом CAN (устройством):

```
// поднять интерфейс CAN1
sudo modprobe can
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000
sudo ip link set can0 up
// отправка сообщения с устройства
sudo cansend can0 '111#11aa'
// приём данных
sudo candump can0
```

---

*Примечание переводчика, SocketCAN встроен в Linux ядро и использует сетевую подсистему Linux.*